# Поиск и добавление текста

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Суть в следующем: содержимое страницы формируется по шаблону. Используется библиотека Mustache для формирования страницы:

```
html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
```

`template` - это шаблон страницы, который нужно заполнить. 
`json` - это объект json, который получен из строки json:

```
json = JSON.parse(json);
```

Mustache.to_html формирует страницу, содержимое которой присваивается переменной html.
Переменная html затем выводиться как готовая страница

```
document.write(html)
```

Содержимое наполнения представляет собой JSON строку.
Файл, который формирует страницу:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >    
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="content://com.example/main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src='content://com.example/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="content://com.example/mustache.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body class="two_background">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var html, json, template;
                jQuery(document).ready(function()
                {
                    jQuery.get('Template.txt', {},function(temp)
                    {
                        template = temp;
                    }, 'text')

                    jQuery.get('data.txt', {} ,function(jso)
                    {
                    json = jso;
                    }, 'text')

                    jQuery('#click').click(function()
                    {
                        json = JSON.parse(json);
                        html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
                        document.write(html);
                    })
                });
            </script>
            <br /><br />
            <div align="center">
                <input type="button" class="mainButton2" value="  ClickMe!!!  " id="click"/>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Содержимое файла, содержащего JSON строку:

```
{
"noData":false,
"activity_empty":"No Data",
"one":[
    {"Id":"111222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",     "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"222222", "image_visible":false, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",    "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"333222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_decline.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700", "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk, IL",

"tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",     "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"444222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_accept.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",  "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"555222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",     "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"}
     ]
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, или подскажите, где "копать" в следующем:
после загрузки файла с JSON строкой в переменную json, перед "парсингом" (раскладыванием строки на объект) необходимо произвести поиск с добавлением текста в переменной json, следующего рода.

Допустим, ищем (`str = "/"image/":/"/","`), после поиска выполняет проверку `if(str == ("/"image/":/"/"," || "/"image/":/"/",")`, если верно, то после этой строчки `"/"image/":/"/","` в переменной json добавляем,

допустим,  `"/"image_visible/":false,"`; если не верно, т.е в `image` после ":" в кавычках что-то содержится, то добавляем `"/"image_visible/":true,"`. Есть пару проблем:

- Первая, что подстрока, которую ищем, может оканчиваться запятой или нет и если `if(str == ("/"image/":/"/"," || "/"image/":/"/",")` дает отрицательный результат, надо знать, перед вставляемой строкой нужно ли добавлять запятую или нет.
- Вторая: нужно знать после вставляемой строки, идут еще строки или она последняя и после нее будет "}", чтобы знать добавлять или нет после вставляемой строки запятую.
  Это делается для того, чтобы избавить приходящий объект в JSON строке от булевых полей, которые служат для отображения или скрытия полей.

В идеале надо, чтобы JSON строка была такая:

```
{
"noData":false,
"activity_empty":"No Data",
"one":[
    {"Id":"111222" "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",    "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"222222", "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",   "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"333222", "image":"ic_decline.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700", "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk, IL",

"tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",     "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"444222", "image":"ic_accept.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",    "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"},
    {"Id":"555222", "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456", "tv_pay":"2,700",   "tv_Date":"jan 26 4:15 PM", "tv_deliveryDate":"jan 30 4:15 PM", "tv_source":"Edwardskkk,

IL", "tv_destination":"Buckeye, AZ",    "activity_weight":"Weight", "tv_weight":"4000", "activity_miles":"Miles", "tv_miles":"1234"}
     ]
}
```

а поле "`image_visible`" добавлялось. Это просто пример, в других файлах таких полей, которые нужно добавлять больше.

Файл шаблона имеет следующий вид:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="content://com.example/main.css" />
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendID(id)
        {
            Function.sendID(id);
        }
    </script>
    <body class="two_background">
        {{#noData}}
            <div class="dividerLine"></div><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div align="center" class="label color_gray">{{activity_empty}}</div>
        {{/noData}}
        {{#one}}
            <div onclick="sendID('{{Id}}')">
                <div>{{#image_visible}}<IMG src="{{image}}">&nbsp;{{/image_visible}}<span class="label color_blue">{{tv_Id}}</span>&nbsp;<span class="font_18 color_red">{{tv_pay}}</span></div><br />
                <div class="label_height">
                    <div align="center" class="label">{{tv_Date}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{tv_deliveryDate}}</div><br />
                    <div align="center" class="font_18">{{tv_source}}&nbsp;<IMG src="ic_pic.png">&nbsp;{{tv_destination}}</div><br />
                </div>
                <div class="font_18"><span class="label color_gray">{{activity_weight}}</span>&nbsp;{{tv_weight}}&nbsp;<span class="label color_gray">{{activity_miles}}</span>&nbsp;{{tv_miles}}</div>
            </div>
            <HR>
        {{/one}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы конечно старались, писали это всё - но не понятно.

Comment: Немного подправил, может так более понятно.

Comment: @exec +1 

Я почти ничего не понял - а то что понял - то в ответе json нужно сделать replace.

Почему бы это не сделать на стороне сервера ?

Comment: Зачем это нужно! В шаблоне, есть куски кода  которые должны отображать или нет, в зависимости от того в JSON объекте, определенные строки содержат значения или нет. Например: {{#image_visible}}<IMG src="{{image}}">&nbsp;{{/image_visible}}
если поле image, в JSON объекте, пустое, то этот кусок кода не нужно отображать,   "/"image_visible/":false,", бодавляем в строку JSON. Это поле нужно только для шаблона!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тоже самое, только немного другим путем:

```
$(sometext.one).each ( function(ind, el) {
    if (el.image) el['image_visible']=true; else el['image_visible']=false
});
```

Допустим имеем исходный json:

```
sometext = {
"noData":false,
"activity_empty":"No Data",
"one":[
    {"Id":"111222", "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456"},
    {"Id":"222222", "image":"", "tv_Id":"123456"}
     ]
}
```

На выходе получим:

```
sometext = {
"noData":false,
"activity_empty":"No Data",
"one":[
    {"Id":"111222", "image_visible":true, "image":"ic_new.png", "tv_Id":"123456"},
    {"Id":"222222", "image_visible":false, "image":"", "tv_Id":"123456"}
     ]
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Reh7b/)

Comment: У меня в приходящей JSON строке не будет этих полей, например, как описывал выше image_visible не будет в приходящей строке, это поле надо будет добавить в самом файле, перед заполнением шаблона. Как описано выше, я добавлю новые поля со значением? Голова уже полностью забита и я не соображаю =)

Comment: Изменил ответ в соответствии с комментарием

Comment: Не добовляет новое поле!!!

Comment: Ну как же не добавляет? Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Reh7b/

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно перед парсингом ничего делать. Зачем работать со строкой если можно с json? Делайте после парсинга, перед передачей в Mustache.

```
jQuery('#click').click(function()
{
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    json.one = $.map(json.one, function(el, idx){
       //тут преобразования элемента массива
       //например
       el['image_visible']=true;
       return el;    
    });
    html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
    document.write(html);
});
```

Comment: не добовляет новое поле!!! Здесь, по моему, оно ищит просто поле и меняет его значение?????!!????